# On hover of any of the li elements in the submenu (2nd ul element) how to change color of the first ul li - ONLY both span icons?

Tags: css, css-selectors

i'm trying to make the color of both icons in my first ul li span i class elements (which is before and after "a" element) change color but i can't seem to target them correctly.

i have managed to get my original code working by hovering every single a/icons seperately and changing their color but i don't want that. i want to change the color of only parent li icons when i hover inside the 2nd(submenu) li element i.e. only submenu active of its parent li should change color of icons

any explanation would be appreciated or resources for learning to target correctly.
only pure css answers thank you.

Here is my css & html code -

```css
/* testing if it works by changing background color of li element */
.navigaton li > ul > li:hover .navigaton li{
  background: pink;
}

/* only the face icons(expressions removed from the html code to make it easier) which are being dynmically repeated from my controller needs to change color */
.navigaton li > ul > li:hover .navigaton li span i{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
        <md-content layout-padding>
          <div style="padding: 0px 16px;">
            <div ng-model="states.activeItem" ></div>
            <ul class="navigation">
              <div class="" layout="column">
                    <li md-ink-ripple="#ebeef4" ng-repeat="item in items" class="item {{item.id}}" ng-class="{'active': item.id == states.activeItem}" ng-click="states.activeItem=item.title">
                      <span>
                        <i class="material-icons md-24 center-icons">face</i>
                      </span>
                      <a class="title" ng-href="">item 1</a>
                      <span>
                        <i class="material-icons md-18 subicon-openstate" id="test-icons">face</i>
                      </span>
                      <ul class="submenu" id="submenu-item-hover">
                        <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.subItems" class="subItem">
                          <a href=>subitem 1</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: CSS does not have a parent selector yet, you should use Javascript to do this kind of behavior. Are you interested on a Javascript solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not any CSS parent selector supported yet. The only way to do what you want is with Javascript.

Here is a quick example on how to do it. Javascript `onmouseover` and `onmouseleave` events respectively add and remove an `active`  class on the parent menu when a submenu is hovered.

Then you can apply any CSS rules with your `li.active` to apply some style on your icons.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll("ul > li > ul > li");

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].onmouseover = function (event) {
   var li = event.srcElement;
   if (li.tagName !== "LI") li = li.parentElement; // if relatedTarget = span inside li, li = relatedTarget.parentElement
    
    var parentLi = li.parentElement.parentElement; // li -> ul -> li
    parentLi.classList.add("active");
  }
  items[i].onmouseleave = function (event) {
   var li = event.srcElement;
   if (li.tagName !== "LI") li = li.parentElement; // if relatedTarget = span inside li, li = relatedTarget.parentElement
    
    var parentLi = li.parentElement.parentElement; // li -> ul -> li
    parentLi.classList.remove("active");
  }
}
```

```css
li.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Menu 1</span></li>
  <li>
    <span>Menu 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Submenu 2.1</span></li>
      <li><span>Submenu 2.2</span></li>
      <li><span>Submenu 2.3</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Menu 3</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Submenu 3.1</span></li>
      <li><span>Submenu 3.2</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that it's not supported yet. I will try out the javascript method which you wrote. thanks again for the help!.

Comment: Do not hesitate to ask if you need help setting it up, and validation the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: i used your js code and put it in my app.js file of my angular application and then in css i tried to use this but the color doesn't change                                                                          .navigation li.active:hover md-content ul li span i{
  color: blue;
}

Comment: .submenu li:hover md-content ul li.active span i{ color: blue;}  targeting the submenu li and changing the color to blue of parent icons also won't work. Am i doing this wrong? do i need to do add jquery? if possible could you write out the correct css code to do that with my given html code sir.

Comment: forget about selector `:hover` with this technique, the class `active` will be applied directly on the parent `li`, so you can use directly something like `li.active xx yy zz`. it should be something like `.navigation li.active i` in your case.

Comment: thanks for your help but i did it through css only, maybe i was targeting wrong but this is what i did -  .navigation li:hover .subicon-openstate { color:#0e66da;cursor: pointer;} .navigation li:hover .center-icons {color: #0e66da;cursor: pointer;}  This is working perfectly fine for my use case for now. Also,could you suggest me some css animation libraries cause i'm new to angular js1.x version and heard jquery is not the angular way of doing things inside Angular js.